# Where the plastic sticker should be installed?

Tags: glass-bed

With my Anet ET4, I also received a plastic sticker. I assume this should be stuck onto glass, not to a metal bed. If I understand this right, when sticking this to glass, I will damage the glass and I cannot use the glass as a bed in the future if I change my mind and decide to experiment with glass again.

Isn't better to buy another glass and stick the plastic there? Or is better to buy some completely different sticker? I have many problems with adhesion on Anet ET4, so looking for options. Any ideas?

Comment: can you confirm that your "sticker" is a PEI sheet? It's common to have PEI with 3M super-strong adhesive to attach to a print bed. It provides fairly strong adhesion on a heated bed, but releases when cool.

Comment: Yes, it is black 3M PEI sheet, which is included

Comment: You can always just turn the glass around if you want to print directly onto it

Comment: PEI would not damage the glass if your intent is to remove it later. A heat gun will soften the adhesive and allow destructive removal of the PEI sheet and non-destructive removal from the glass. @towe's suggestion to turn the glass over is valid. Your suggestion to use a second sheet of glass is also useful.

Comment: Many thanks for all hints, i think i will use second glass to avoid using heat gun later, just to save some time. Glass is cheap, so why not to have 2 ;-)

Comment: Also print/build surfaces can be expensive as well as a pain to remove.  You don't want to remove it until it is damaged.  Removing it destroys the print surface.

Answer (score 1):

Besides a heat gun, heating the bed some can also help removing the tape-like print surface/adhesion layer.  Using a puddy knife carefully can help prying up the adhesion layer.  The only danger to the glass is mechanically breaking it.  Avoid mashing a sharp point perpendicular to the surface of the glass or pounding the surface.

Most of the work removing the surface is cleaning off the adhesive left by the adhesion layer on the glass.  A cleaner rated as a degreaser or IPA (at least 90% IPA) helps remove the adhesive.  Many of the hand sanitizers with at least 70% alcohol will work if the remainder is hydrocarbons with little water.  You can remove the hydrocarbons left with soap and water.

Here is an example of a print surface/adhesion layer (black) on a glass bed (white).  The object being printed is blue.

[image]